# python selenium fill input whit same names

Tags: python, html, selenium

i need fill input in tables whit selenium, bat have small problem, the inputs have same name, exemple html :

```
<table class="box active" id="datiReceiverBox">
<tbody><tr>
<td><label>Nome*</label><input class="chars24 gray_bg" disabled="" type="text"></td><td style="width:54%" colspan="2" class="btnSelReceiver"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn chars14 show_msg_assenza_contratto"><span>SELEZIONA BENEFICIARIO</span></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn chars14 show_msg_assenza_contratto"><span>SALVA BENEFICIARIO</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Cognome*</label><input class="chars24 gray_bg" disabled="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

need fill label Nome and cognome, how i can do this ? 
My acctual code is :

```
driver = self.driver
driver.get("https://localhost:8443/member/")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(),"Nome"]/input').send_keys("text here")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(),"Cognome"]/input').send_keys("and here")
```